# Worker pool to handle queries

Tags: mysql, go

I'm pretty new to Go and looking for a way to handle 3000 queries using 100 workers and ensuring a connection for every worker (MySQL is already configured with more than 100 connections). This is my attempt:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var query *sql.Stmt

func worker(jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {

    for _ = range jobs {

        _, e := query.Exec("a")

        if e != nil {

            panic(e.Error())
        }

        results <- 1
    }
}

func main() {

    workers := 100

    db, e := sql.Open("mysql", "foo:foo@/foo")

    if e != nil {

        panic(e.Error())
    }

    db.SetMaxOpenConns(workers)
    db.SetMaxIdleConns(workers)

    defer db.Close()

    query, e = db.Prepare("INSERT INTO foo (foo) values(?)")

    if e != nil {

        panic(e.Error())
    }

    total := 30000
    jobs := make(chan int, total)
    results := make(chan int, total)

    for w := 0; w < workers; w++ {

        go worker(jobs, results)
    }

    for j := 0; j < total; j++ {

        jobs <- j
    }

    close(jobs)

    for r := 0; r < total; r++ {

        <-results
    }
}
```

It's working, but I'm not sure if is the best way of doing it.

Please, if you think this is opinion based or is not a good question at all, just mark it to be closed and leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: ["Concurrency is not parallelism" by Rob Pike](http://vimeo.com/49718712) starting at minute 19 -- "a very simple load balancer" that distributes work across some workers.

Comment: @tomwilde, sure, I'm reading it http://talks.golang.org/2012/waza.slide#40 thanks!

Comment: @tomwilde, in that example Rob is not buffering the channels, but if I don't buffer the channels using the total number of jobs then I only get the number of workers as jobs done.

Comment: Main thing I can see is you want a `sync.WaitGroup` for clean shutdown. Can demo.

Comment: @twotwotwo, I started this using sync.WaitGroup but didn't know how to buffer to have a max number of concurrent workers.

Comment: Ah, I forgot something fundamental: without buffering of some sort you have to be draining results as workers insert them. http://play.golang.org/p/251IzyIMnu starts a draining goroutine. My drainer just pushes results on a list; in a real worker-pool scenario with a lot of jobs, you might want the drainer to do something interesting (be the next stage of your app's pipeline, as it were).  Finally, you could just as well put the job inserter in the background goroutine and keep the draining in the foreground.

Comment: Looks a bit confusing right now (I'm sleepy), I'll study it tomorrow, thanks @twotwotwo!

Comment: Simplest way to avoid hanging without buffering: http://play.golang.org/p/7EdxQNlX33. Just inserts jobs in a separate goroutine. `WaitGroup` is really an unrelated thing and it was a little confused (as well as confusing) that I added both in the same example.

Comment: @twotwotwo, I have finally developed something based on your last example and it's working as I wanted. Feel free to add it as an answer with a little explanation so I can accept it and upvote it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got fundamentally works, but to get rid of buffering, you need to be writing to `jobs` and reading from `results` at the same time. Otherwise, your process ends up stuck--workers can't send results because nothing is receiving them, and you can't insert jobs because workers are blocked.

Here's [a boiled-down example on the Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/7EdxQNlX33) of how to do a work queue that pushes jobs in the background as it receives results in `main`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func worker(jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    for _ = range jobs {
        // ...do work here...
        results <- 1
    }
}

func main() {
    workers := 10
    total := 30
    jobs := make(chan int)
    results := make(chan int)

    // start workers
    for w := 0; w < workers; w++ {
        go worker(jobs, results)
    }

    // insert jobs in background
    go func() {
        for j := 0; j < total; j++ {
            jobs <- j
        }
    }()

    // collect results
    for i := 0; i < total; i++ {
        <-results
        fmt.Printf(".")
    }

    close(jobs)
}
```

For that particular code to work, you have to know how many results you'll get. If you don't know that (say, each job could produce zero or multiple results), you can use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to [wait for the workers to finish, then close the result stream](http://play.golang.org/p/aLYn1_3YTs):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func worker(jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for _ = range jobs {
        // ...do work here...
        results <- 1
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    workers := 10
    total := 30
    jobs := make(chan int)
    results := make(chan int)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    // start workers
    for w := 0; w < workers; w++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(jobs, results, wg)
    }

    // insert jobs in background
    go func() {
        for j := 0; j < total; j++ {
            jobs <- j
        }
        close(jobs)
        wg.Wait()
        // all workers are done so no more results
        close(results)
    }()

    // collect results
    for _ = range results {
        fmt.Printf(".")
    }

}
```

There are many other more complicated tricks one can do to stop all workers after an error happens, put results into the same order as the original jobs, or do other things like that. Sounds as if the basic version works here, though.